# How to find the point that is the minimum total distance from $N$ points in an arbitrary dimension?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given a set of $k-\text{dimensional}$ points $S$, how do you find the point $p$ that minimizes the sum of the distances from $p$ to each point in $S?$

Comment: So you mean to minimize the sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\text{number of points}} \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{\text{dimensions}} (\xi_j-x_{ij})^2}
$$
for a given set of points{$x_i$} , where the $i$th of them has coordinates $x_{ij}$?

Comment: Yes. I suppose you would be trying to find the value that would minimize that sum.

Comment: denote the sum as $f(\xi_1,...,\xi_k)$, since it is a multivariable function. Now a necessary condition is that all partial derivatives must vanish simultaneously, but that is not sufficient

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median